# Why does my text keep moving my image down?

Tags: html, css

How can I wrap my "contenteditable" text around the image but prevent the image from moving down as the text proceeds to the next line?

```css
.note {
  width: 280px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 2;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-family: Note;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">Pellentesque pharetra mi lacus, vitae rhoncus nulla hendrerit vitae. Vestibulum nec lectus sed tortor maximus commodo.
  <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract/1/" height="30" width="30" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you've so put so nicely your example here then please add it on fiddle

Comment: there is no image but this shows the problem when you type. http://jsfiddle.net/1me4Lw00/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image before the text, then apply `float:right` to allow the text to flow around the image and position the image on the top right corner.

```css
.note {
  width: 280px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 2;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-family: Note;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#close {
  float: right;
}
#close img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
  <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/X-icon.png"/>
  </span>
  Pellentesque pharetra mi lacus, vitae rhoncus nulla hendrerit vitae. Vestibulum nec lectus sed tortor maximus commodo.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move:

```
<span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract/1/" height="30" width="30" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
</span>
```

before the text and it should wrap around the image as you want. You don't need to add float or anything.

Here's a jsfiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/fu9epb1s/3/

(I have edited the image paths for example's sake)

```css
.note {
    width: 280px;
    height: 130px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 2;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Note;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://www.allaboutkidsng.com/images/sticky-notes.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="note" contenteditable="true"><span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/abstract/1/" height="30" width="30" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
  </span>Type here</div>
```

Comment: hmmm i clicked the link but it showed me the home page of jsfiddle. So i added the min-height but it still didn't work.

Comment: Check the updated answer @usernameisnotprogrammedyet